# How can the STL headers be found from inside a C++ program?

Tags: c++, directory, compiler-construction, include, c++17

I'm coding a script to recursively document all the `#include` directives inside a `.c`, `.cpp`, `.h`, or `.hpp` file. However, I need to be able to locate the folder where the STL headers are located from within this program so that I can search that folder, then open that header to search it (and so on).

Obviously the compiler knows where these files are, so is there a way to get that information from the compiler? Also, I'd like to save the path as an `std::filesystem::path` object.

If a portable solution is impossible, a solution for Windows using MSVC 2019 would work fine for my purposes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand: Why do you need to search it inside the program?

Comment: It depends on the specific SDK used.

Comment: Notice that standard headers are not necessary files.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to make any scrips, `/showincludes` compiler option can be used for this purpose.